# My dev site is showing in Google search. Is there a way to not show it

Tags: wordpress, web

I was doing a generic search on our domain and noticed that my dev site showed up. How do hide my dev site from the public? My sites are built using wordpress and I am looking into the settings now but I think it has something to with DNS maybe but not 100% sure.

Comment: wordpress is infamous for its lack of findability in search engines. how on earth did you get your dev site to show up? Find the keywords section and take the keywords out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `robots.txt` text file that sits in the root directory of your website which tells web crawlers what you want (or don't want) them to index.

*Edit:*

As you're using WordPress, log in to your Dashboard and navigate to: **Settings** » **Reading** » **Search Engine Visibility**, then select "Discourage search engines from indexing this site".

If you're planning on having a Development/Staging environment, I would recommend setting up a `.htpasswd` file to [prevent unauthorised access](http://dev.bluemwhitew.com) (including crawlers/robots).

**Resources:**

- [The Web Robots Pages](http://www.robotstxt.org)
- [Manage User Files for Basic Authentication](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html)

Comment: Ok thanks turned on discouragement and will give the htpasswd page a shot.